# Click an OK button in a prompt using Python Request

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, python-requests, click

So basically, I wanted to automate this using Python's Requests Module

Log in the website > Time out > Sign out

I've done automating the website log in using the ".post()" code.
But I am stuck in clicking the Time out button because it doesn't show any Form Data when I tried to inspect it using Google Chrome's Inspect. I used the same ".post()" code. it actually doesn't work. I noticed that there is a **PROMPT** **WINDOW** that have buttons OK and CANCEL, which you need to click OK before it can proceed which is also the only recorded network activity in the inspect menu when I clicked it. here are the results in Chrome's Inspect if it can help.

```
GENERAL
    Request URL: https://blah.blah.com/auth/WebLogSubmit.igx?type=OUT
    Request Method: POST
    Status Code: 200 OK
    Remote Address: 1.11.11.1
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
RESPONSE HEADERS
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    Content-Length: 320
    Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
    Date: Tue, 26 Feb 2019 23:38:49 GMT
    Pragma: no-cache
    Server: Jetty(9.4.14.v20181114)
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
REQUEST HEADERS
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 0
    Cookie: _lastloggeddate=off; _lastloggeddate=on; JSESSIONID=0HVVf1JLkZLWllMLbSLoG2o14ZXLHiFB4yq2am+VAHBAsKGAt0Avkgacwe9qly7UBF3Ga2As/R0+ChgF7GEQJA==; AWSELB=E204C7B7ED3B76034B4DCF9D0AA226E459847982290B43FAF19399EF5AC1BC948D033EAAF9221BD4FB9718F6; _ga=GA1.2.1551220185; _gid=GA1.2.1551220185
    Host: blah.blah.com
    Origin: https://blah.blah.com
    Referer: https://blah.blah.com/auth/index.htm
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
QUERY STRING PARAMETERS
    type: OUT

    WebLogSubmit.igx?type=OUT
```

Comment: You may need [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) here.

Comment: @MichaelButscher is it possible to just do it on the back end side?

Comment: Hard to tell but if the communication between the webpage and the server is accurately recorded it should be possible to replay it with Python code using requests library.